Shifting lines of integration in the complex plane
Something remains quite unclear to me about shifting lines of integration. Does there exist a precise theorem for this ? I came to think about this after reading the proof of Theorem 10.2.17 of Number Theory: Volume II: Analytic and Modern Tools (see bottom of page 179).
For instance, it is not difficult to show the following with the residue theorem: if $f$ is a meromorphic function whose poles are $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, and $f(x + iy) \to 0$ when $|y| \to \infty$ uniformly in $x \in \left[u, v\right]$, then, assuming the following integrals exist, $$\int_{v-i\infty}^{v+i\infty} f(z) \mathrm dz = \int_{u-i\infty}^{u+i\infty} f(z) \mathrm dz + 2 \pi i \sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm{Res}(f, a_k)$$ for real numbers $u < v$ large enough to enclose the poles.
But what if $f$ doesn't vanish when moving away from the real axis ? Everyone seems to ignore that, and I haven't been able to found proper documentation.

These inverse Laplace transforms assume that  $f(z)$ is analytic for all $Re[z]\lt v$ in the left half plane and its absolute value falls off on half circles closing its diameter in imaginary direction  faster than the lenght of the half circle enclosing the poles.  The reason is that the poles of the transfer function wrt to frequency  imply an imaginary causal damping summand in  the exponential such that the solutions go to zero in time forward direction.

You create an axis-parllell box of 4 lines, the two you have (but ended at very large positive and negative imaginary values) and two lines conecting the endpoints.
The curve integral of the created closed curve is given by residue calculus if the curve integrals on the lines parallell to the real axis can be calculated.
You then need to investigate the behaviour of those integral as the ending points of the lines parallell to the imaginary axis goes to positive and negative infinity.

An addition: you must remember to choose the orientation of the lines so that the rectangle can be traversed without "breaking the traffic rules"
